# Get position of point on curve

Tags: three.js

I have a CatmullRomCurve3 created from an array of Vector3 points.

```
const curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points);
```

I would like to know the position of those same points on the curve (in a range from 0 to 1). Basically the inverse of `.getPointAt()` where the first point would be at 0, the last at 1.

I would like to do this in order to subdivide the curve in an equal number of segments *between each of the points that I used to create the curve*. So for example getting 10 subdivisions between point 0 and point 1, 10 between point 1 and point 2, and so on.

Comment: Let me get this straight; you have a curve, and you want to know each vertex's position, but not in x-y-z coordinates, but on a 0%-100% progress along the curve? If so, do you need it to be calculated during creation of the curve, or do you need to find these out AFTER the curve has already been generated?

Comment: @Marquizzo Correct. I generate the curve myself, so I know the 'xyz's. It can therefore be calculated either during or after the creation. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure there's a mathematical approach to your question, but a simple workaround would be to:

1. Create the original curve with an array or `Vector3`s.
2. Create a duplicate curve with the same array, that stops at the `Vector3` that you're searching for.
3. Take the length of the second curve, divide by length of original curve, and you'll get your [0, 1] position.

**In code:**

```
// Create original curve
var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
    new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 10 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( -5, 5, 5 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 5, -5, 5 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( 50, 0, 50 )
], false );

var searchPoint = new THREE.Vector3( 5, -5, 5 ); // Point we're looking for
var searchArray = [];   // Array for second curve
var uPosition = null; // Result is null for now

// Loop through curve.points to find our final point
for(var i = 0; i < curve.points.length; i++){
    searchArray.push(curve.points[i]);

    // Exit loop once point has been found
    if(searchPoint.equals(curve.points[i])){
        // Create shorter curve that stops at desired point
        var curve2 = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(searchArray);

        // Result is short length / original length
        uPosition = curve2.getLength() / curve.getLength();
        break;
    }
}

// Result is null if position not found
console.log(uPosition);
```

Comment: Nice workaround. Since I need the position of all the knots that make up the curve, I could build it incrementally adding them to the `points` array, and getting the length after each step. I'll wait to accept the answer to see if there's a _proper_ way, but I doubt it.

Comment: If after all, `uPosition` is not `null`, will `curve.getPoint(uPosition)` give the same vector that equals `searchPoint`?